# What is the area of the shape defined by the locus of a point on a circle rolling around another circle?

Tags: differential-geometry, circles, area

What is the area of a shape, which I'm deeming a 'cylicoid', which is defined as follows:
Circle A of radius 1 is held stationary.
Circle B of radius 1 has a point on its rim which traces a path as it is rolled around circle A.
A cyclicoid is the shape enclosed by the path of the point on circle B's rim. It looks roughly like a heart shape.

In parametric terms, a cyclicoid can be shown to be:

x = 2 cos t + cos (2t)

y = 2 sin t + sin (2t)

However, I'm unsure how to integrate this parametric function to find its area. Any ideas on how to do it and what the answer is? Thanks.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx
This is a pretty good guide for the topic. Paul's notes are great.

Basically, there are two ways to do it, and they are pretty much equivalent. Take the derivative of one function, multiply that by the other function, then integrate.

Comment: The shape is an *[epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid)*, more specifically a [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid), and its area is given in the Wikipedia article. How to compute the [area of a parametric curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#Area_in_calculus) is also on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

By stokes' theorem, if $\gamma$ is a closed curve in the plane, then the area it encloses is given by$$S=\int dxdy=\int_\gamma ydx.$$